# How to call setState alongside FutureBuilder in flutter without resetting the ExpansionTile?

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart, flutter-layout

Inside every `ExpansionTile` I've to call a `FutureBuilder` to get the dynamic data from server. The Future Builder Being Triggered only on Expanded so as to show the dynamic data as children of `ExpansionTile`.

```
 ListView(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
    children: widget.list.map((item) {
      return Card(
        elevation: 5,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white70, width: 1),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
        child: ExpansionTile(
          leading: Icon(
            item["status"] != 3 ? Icons.warning : Icons.verified_user,
            color: item["status"] != 3 ? Colors.yellow[900] : Colors.green,
          ),
          title: Text(item["service_type"]),
          subtitle: Text(DateFormat('dd MMMM yyyy')
              .format(DateTime.parse(item["created_at"]))
              .toString()),
          onExpansionChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              timelineValue = value;
            });
          },
          children: <Widget>[
            timelineValue
                ? FutureBuilder(
                    future: getTimeline(timelineValue, item["id"]),
                    builder:
                        (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        // print(jsonDecode(snapshot.data.body).runtimeType);
                        Map map = jsonDecode(snapshot.data.body);
                        var currentstatus =
                            CurrentStatusModel.fromJson(map);
                        return Card(
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            side:
                                BorderSide(color: Colors.white70, width: 1),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          ),
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                color: secondaryColour),
                            height: 250,
                            padding:
                                EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, right: 8, left: 8),
                            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                              child: Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  getTimelinetile(
                                      heading: "ഫോം ലഭിച്ചു.",
                                      subtitle:
                                          "സേവനത്തിനായുള്ള നിങ്ങളുടെ അപേക്ഷ ലഭിച്ചു.",
                                      isFirst: true,
                                      isLast: false,
                                      side: "left",
                                      isInactive: false),
                                  currentstatus.isProcessing == 1
                                      ? getTimelinetile(
                                          heading: "പ്രോസസ്സിംഗ് ആരംഭിച്ചു",
                                          subtitle: currentstatus
                                                      .isProcessingDesc !=
                                                  null
                                              ? currentstatus
                                                  .isProcessingDesc
                                              : "ഞങ്ങളുടെ സ്റ്റാഫുകൾ‌ ഇപ്പോൾ‌ നിങ്ങളുടെ അപ്ലിക്കേഷൻ‌ പരിശോധിക്കുന്നു.",
                                          isFirst: false,
                                          isLast: false,
                                          side: "right",
                                          isInactive: false)
                                      : Container(),
                                  currentstatus.documentsRequired == 1
                                      ? getTimelinetile(
                                          heading: "രേഖകൾ ആവശ്യമാണ്",
                                          subtitle: currentstatus
                                                      .documentsRequiredDesc !=
                                                  null
                                              ? currentstatus
                                                  .documentsRequiredDesc
                                              : "നിങ്ങളുടെ അപേക്ഷയുമായി മുന്നോട്ട് പോകാൻ രേഖകൾ ആവശ്യമാണ്.",
                                          isFirst: false,
                                          isLast: false,
                                          side: "left",
                                          isInactive: false)
                                      : Container(),
                                  currentstatus.documentsRequired == 1
                                      ? getTimelinetile(
                                          heading: currentstatus
                                                      .documentsReceived ==
                                                  1
                                              ? "രേഖകൾ ലഭിച്ചു"
                                              : "രേഖകൾ ഇതുവരെ ലഭ്യമായിട്ടില്ല.",
                                          subtitle: currentstatus
                                                      .documentsReceived ==
                                                  1
                                              ? (currentstatus
                                                          .documentsReceivedDesc !=
                                                      null
                                                  ? currentstatus
                                                      .documentsReceivedDesc
                                                  : "നിങ്ങൾ അയച്ച രേഖകൾ ഇപ്പോൾ ഞങ്ങളുടെ എക്സിക്യൂട്ടീവ് പരിശോധിച്ചുറപ്പിക്കുന്നു.")
                                              : "ഞങ്ങളുടെ സ്റ്റാഫുകൾ നിങ്ങളുടെ ഭാഗത്തു നിന്നുള്ള രേഖകൾക്കായി കാത്തിരിക്കുന്നു.",
                                          isFirst: false,
                                          isLast: false,
                                          side: "right",
                                          isInactive: currentstatus
                                                      .documentsReceived ==
                                                  1
                                              ? false
                                              : true)
                                      : Container(),
                                  currentstatus.paymentRequired == 1
                                      ? getTimelinetile(
                                          heading: "പേയ്‌മെന്റ് ആവശ്യമാണ്.",
                                          subtitle:
                                              "ഞങ്ങളുടെ സേവനവുമായി തുടരാൻ പേയ്‌മെന്റ് ആവശ്യമാണ്.",
                                          isLast: false,
                                          isFirst: false,
                                          side: "left",
                                          isInactive: false,
                                        )
                                      : Container(),
                                  currentstatus.paymentRequired == 1
                                      ? getTimelinetile(
                                          heading: currentstatus
                                                      .paymentReceived ==
                                                  1
                                              ? "പേയ്മെന്റ് ലഭിച്ചു"
                                              : "പേയ്‌മെന്റ് ഇതുവരെ ലഭിച്ചിട്ടില്ല.",
                                          subtitle: "test",
                                          isFirst: false,
                                          isLast: false,
                                          side: "right",
                                          isInactive: currentstatus
                                                      .paymentReceived ==
                                                  1
                                              ? false
                                              : true)
                                      : Container(),
                                  getTimelinetile(
                                      heading: currentstatus.formFinished ==
                                              1
                                          ? "സേവനം പൂർത്തിയായി"
                                          : "സേവനം പൂർത്തീകരിച്ചിട്ടില്ല",
                                      subtitle: currentstatus
                                                  .formFinished ==
                                              1
                                          ? "നിങ്ങളുടെ അപ്ലിക്കേഷൻ ഇതുവരെ പൂർത്തീകരിച്ചിട്ടില്ല."
                                          : "നിങ്ങളുടെ അപ്ലിക്കേഷൻ ഇതുവരെ പൂർത്തിയായിട്ടില്ല.",
                                      isLast: true,
                                      isFirst: false,
                                      side: "left",
                                      isInactive:
                                          currentstatus.formFinished == 1
                                              ? false
                                              : true),
                                  Card(
                                    color: Colors.grey[900],
                                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      side: BorderSide(
                                          color: Colors.white70, width: 1),
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                    ),
                                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                    child: Container(
                                      child: Column(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          ListTile(
                                            title: Text(
                                              'example',
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 18,
                                                  color: Colors.white),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                      if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        return Container();
                      }
                      return Container(
                          height: 30.0,
                          child: LoadingIndicator(
                            indicatorType: Indicator.ballBeat,
                            color: primaryColour,
                          ));
                    })
                : Container()
          ],
        ),
      );
    }).toList(),
  ),
```

and the future function being -

```
Future getTimeline(value, id) async {
    if (timelineValue == true) {
      return await http.get(
          "http://" + restEndpoint + "/akshaya/public/api/get_timeline/$id");
    }
  }
```

The issue is for every `onExpansionChange` the `setState` is being called which rebuilds the widget tree and mess up the current state of the `ExpansionTile`. To be specific when collapsing one `ExpansionTile`, children of every other `ExpansionTile` collapses with the trailing botton pointing to Expanded mode.

Comment: Please copy your code correctly. There are open tags and missing closures that make it difficult to make sense and help you. Also, can you please explain your last paragraph a bit more explicitly? Is your widget rebuilding in a loop due to the `setStates` and future builders?

Comment: No, its not looping. The number of ExpansionTiles is dynamic and again the content inside Expanded body (children) of every ExpansionTile is received after a  http get method for which i use the `FutureBuilder`.  But when multiple `ExpansionTiles` are expanded and then when trying to close one 'ExpansionTile', the expanded body of every other `ExpansionTile` closes leaving the Expand/Collapse button still pointing in Expanded direction. The issue is happening when I use setState inside `onExpansionChanged` callback. @JoãoSoares

Comment: I want to trigger the FutureBuilder only when the `ExpansionTile` is expanded. so without the `setState` I cant trigger the `FutureBuilder`. Please ask if you want more details and sorry for poor English. @JoãoSoares

Comment: I think I understand the issue now, and I believe I've seen it before. I'll try to replicate it locally.

Comment: @JoãoSoares Thanks for reaching back and for your time. I hope you could solve it.

Comment: I was reading your code once again. Is your objective to only load the data inside the ExpansionTiles when they are expanded instead of loading all the data when the ExpansionTile widget is loaded?

Comment: @JoãoSoares My aim is to load the data only after the `ExpansionTile` is Expanded. The `ExpansionTile` title is already loaded in the previous page but the expansion body data is only loaded after the `ExpansionTile` is expanded. When expanding i want to rebuild the FutureBuilder.

Comment: @JoãoSoares Hoping to hear from you if had gone through the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be, that you have a single variable `timelineValue` that you use for
every expansion.

You need *one variable per tile*.

Add another boolean property to whatever class your `widget.list` holds and use the respective property of the current item instead of your single variable.